# How do I find detached debug symbols for decompilation?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am trying to debug a segfault without code a binary in a nonstandard path (specifically in /frs/alg/alg/bin/) and I was noticing that the decompiled code has fewer symbols than when debugging under gdb. I am assuming that the debug symbols are detached, but Where should I look to find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the binary has [detached debug information](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html); if `gdb` is able to find this without any particular configuration, it should be in one of

- a build-id based file under `/usr/lib/debug/.build-id`;
- a `.debug` file alongside the binary;
- a `.debug` file in `/frs/alg/alg/bin/.debug`;
- a `.debug` file in `/usr/lib/debug/frs/alg/alg/bin`.

The binary might have a debug link pointing at the detached information; look for a `.gnu_debuglink` section in the binary. To find its build-id (if any), look for a section named `.note.gnu.build-id` or something along those lines.

Comment: In my case the file had to end in a `.dbg` for some reason, a `.debug` didn't work